# Custom dependency property not working

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a panorama control whose data template is as follows:-

```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateCategory">
            <Grid >
                <localControls:PanoramaItem BookmarkedTopics="{Binding Path=BookmarkedTopics,ElementName=root}" Topics="{Binding Topics}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

The root is the name of the usercontrol in which the panorama is defined. and BookmarkedTopics in Path is DependencyProperty in root (usercontrol) whose definition is as follows:-

```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty BookmarkedTopicsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BookmarkedTopics",
           typeof(ObservableCollection<Topic>), typeof(MainPage), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<Topic>()));
        public ObservableCollection<Topic> BookmarkedTopics
        {
            get { return GetValue(BookmarkedTopicsProperty) as ObservableCollection<Topic>; }
            set
            {

                SetValue(BookmarkedTopicsProperty, value);
            }
        }
```

BookmarkedTopics gets set in MainPage_Loaded and it never null or empty collection (irrelevant to my question but still thought to mention it). BookmarkedTopics is Dependency property in PanoramaItem also whose definition is:-

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BookmarkedTopicsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BookmarkedTopics",
       typeof(ObservableCollection<Topic>), typeof(PanoramaItem), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<Topic>()));
    public ObservableCollection<Topic> BookmarkedTopics
    {
        get { return GetValue(BookmarkedTopicsProperty) as ObservableCollection<Topic>; }
        set
        {

            SetValue(BookmarkedTopicsProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

Problem is when the the BookmarkedTopics get set in MainPage_Loaded why is the setter of BookmarkedTopics in PanoramaItem not fired? Any bug that you can see in the code?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does the code work anyway?  Whilst the question seems to focus on the property implementation (which is wrong and needs correcting) I suspect the real issue is in the binding.  Is the data template in the MainPage.xaml?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones :- Yes it is in MainPage.xaml.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When a dependency property value is assigned by a binding or an animation Silverlight uses the `SetValue` method directly using the appropriate `DependencyProperty` static field.   Hence the setter method of the POCO property is not called.

If you need code to run when a dependency property is assigned you need to use code like this:-

```
    public ObservableCollection<Topic> BookmarkedTopics
    {
        get { return GetValue(BookmarkedTopicsProperty) as ObservableCollection<Topic>; }
        set { SetValue(BookmarkedTopicsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BookmarkedTopicsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "BookmarkedTopics",
            typeof(ObservableCollection<Topic>),
            typeof(MainPage),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, OnBookmarkedTopicsPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnBookmarkedTopicsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainPage source = d as MainPage;
        ObservableCollection<Topic> value = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<Topic>;

        // Code here to handle any work when the value has changed
    }
```

Note also the default value for this dependency property is `null`.  Do not use an instance of a mutable type for a dependency property default because that one instance is then shared by all instances of your class.

Comment: - Very well explained. Got in my head quickly. You should be a tutor. Your all answers are to the point and solves the issue perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

I know there are issues with using ObservableCollection types in dependancy properties and I know for sure you shouldn't give it a default value of a new ObservableCollection. Instead you should register it as ReadOnly (note this doesn't just mean make the definition of it read only).

This MSDN post describes it in more detail.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/e19f9f98-9007-4dbd-b1c4-664a511c0846/

Comment: I didn't understand what you are telling. There is no such static method as RegisterReadOnly in WP7 Silverlight. Also will using this method solve my issue?

Comment: What he is saying is that if you use a collection type in a dependency property then every time you set the value you destroy the original collection as its removed and replaced with the new one rather than it editing the original. to fix this create a read only property that contains the collection so that the orginal collection can't be removed only edited